# Accessing elements inside ControlTemplate xaml by c#

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a wpf application there i have ControlTemplate in the App.xaml. This ControlTemplate contains Grid and Then Canvas.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PinTemplate" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
        <Grid x:Name="grid2" HorizontalAlignment="left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"   >
            <Canvas x:Name="ContentPopup" Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                <StackPanel  x:Name="stackPanel1" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-20"  Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"

                                                            Margin="0" TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.FontSize="10" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas>
                <Ellipse Name="Ellips12" Fill="AliceBlue" Opacity="0.7" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"  Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="5" Width="25"     />
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat }" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue" FontSize="13" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"  Margin="10,7,10,0">
                </TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

I need help to access the Grid and the Canvas inside this ControlTemplate from the mainWindow.xaml.cs. 
I want to change the attribut "Visibility" for it when PropertyChanged or when ViewChangeEnd event.

that what i have tried but doesnt work.

```
        ControlTemplate ct = Application.Current.Resources["PinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        Grid gr = ct.Resources["grid2"] as Grid;
        gr.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

and even this

```
 ControlTemplate ct = Application.Current.Resources["PinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        Grid gr = ct.FindName("grid2", this) as Grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ControlTemplate.FindName` returns the Item only after the template is applied on the control. If you are doing this in `UserControl` you could get it by overriding `OnApplyTemplate`. Or if you are outside the `UserControl` you could use Control.Loaded Event for the same :)
hope it helped :)

Comment: you mean that i should Load the ControlTemplate first ? Like this   ct.LoadContent();

Comment: no, try Finding on UserControl.Loaded Event (the UserControl to which its applied)